# Accessing a control in App.xaml from other pages

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, xna

So, in my **App.xaml (WP8 App)** I have a *MediaElement control*. I have successfully "looped it" through out my WP8 app. (Yes, I know I should be using the XNA Framework but still.)

I'd like to **access it through other App pages and change the control's various properties** for example it's volume etc.

However, I am not sure how do I access it?!
It would be better if you could also explain the difference between the **"FindName"** and **"FindResource"** terms.

Another thing that interests me is, suppose I am able to successfully return a control from a particular page to another page and store it in a say "Temp_Control" (obviously matching the type of the retrieved control), will any of the changes that I make to the "Temp_Control" **also be reflected in the original control?** If not, then how do I implement it that is **set** it?!

Many thanks in advance.

My code that I am using in App.xaml is:-

```
    <!--Application Resources-->
    <Application.Resources>
    <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PQRS"          x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
    <Style  x:Key="RootFrameStyle" TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationFrame">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationFrame">
                    <Grid>
                        <MediaElement x:Name="MediaPlayer" Source="/abcd.mp3" Volume="1" AutoPlay="True" MediaEnded="MediaPlayer_MediaEnded"/>
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure XNA isn't supported for WP8, just so you know. That was a WP7 thing.

Comment: I used the SoundEffect class in my WP8 App. Moreover, there's this [link](http://tutorial.programming4.us/windows_phone/windows-phone-8---using-sound-%28part-1%29---playing-sounds-with-mediaelement,-using-xna-libraries,-playing-sounds-with-xna,-adjusting-playback.aspx) you might want to check out.

Comment: I stand (almost) corrected. There is *limited* support. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx (note, consider linking to actual documentation instead of a random tutorial/blog whenever possible, its more reliable/official)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is exactly not what was required but worked for me and also should do for others too.

**Change in approach:-**

Instead of setting up the controls in App.xaml, I set them up in App.xaml.cs.

Finally, in the Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) event I added it to the Application Resources through

```
      Application.Current.Resources.Add(key,value);
```

**How to access the added controls through other pages:-**

What was basically needed was a sweet simple line of code:-

```
    var obj = App.Current as App;
```

With "obj" you can access the controls/variables in the App.xaml which are obviously global.

For Example:-

```
    var obj = App.Current as App;
    obj.Control_Name.Control_Properties=//whatever you require
```

**So the overall code goes like:-**

```
    //In App.xaml.cs

    public MediaElement m = new MediaElement();

     private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {

        //Set the properties of the MediaElement Control here
        Application.Current.Resources.Add("1", m); //Add it to the Application Resources


    }        


    //In MainPage.xaml.cs say for a Button Click Event
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = App.Current as App;
        obj.m.Play();
    }
```

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out, but thats a pretty ugly design if you ask me

Comment: Hehe, I agree, but I found it pretty easy to implement.

Comment: Remember: easy to implement != easy to maintain/extend/reuse. The easiest design of all is to put everything in main, but that doesn't make it a good idea

Comment: Agreed, but in some scenarios in order to make the system "easy to maintain/extend/reuse" we tend to make it difficult to implement! A live example is the process of Normalization in DBMS. We therefore agreed to introduce the concept of De-Normalization thus accepting redundancies in the database.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that denormalization of a relational database is *not* for ease-of-implementation, but query speed. Queries run against a denormalized database are *much* faster. And the reality is, that until you know when you *should* be denormalizing, it should be normalized, at least to 1'st normal form, if not second. On second thought, 100% sure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc505841.aspx

Comment: And yes, good design typically involves more *effort* (not sure if that means "hard to implement"). In systems of any appreciable complexity though, that trade-off is *always* worth it. Quick ancedote: I wrote a application that accesed a database. We decided to do so via the Dapper library. Several months later, I was asked to add a LINQ To SQL alternative. That was *super easy* because I already had it going through an interface. That good design cost me some effort (having to code the prototypes twice, etc.) but it saved me a *ton* of pain when it had to change.

Comment: If one's database boasts of top notch normalization, it implies multiple tables do exist in the database that need to be accessed in order to complete a fetch/retrieve operation. This reduces the speed that you're talking about. True. Agreed. The problem was caused due to presence the multiple tables. Therefore, redundancies were accepted intentionally so as to balance out. So, I rest my case with the fact that there needs to be a balance in both the implementation as well as the expansion/reusability. Peace. :P

Comment: I agree that there is a balance. On a side note, typically denormalized tables are sometimes kept as seperate "reporting" tables so you can have the query speed against them while maintaining design. Regardless, *where* the correct balance is hotly debated among programmers, so thank you for having a nice, civil discussion with me! Feel free to come by chat once you have 20 rep if you want to talk about it more. I'm usually in the WPF room.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question:

You would need a reference to the original page's instance, at which point you could search through the visual tree for the control. Even better would be to just expose the modification methods as public methods of that control, then those methods would set it through the control name:

```
public SetVideoVolume(int level)
{
   MediaPlayer.Volume = level;
}
```

If you did hold a reference to that control, yes, changes would affect it (you are just holding a reference after all).

`FindName` looks for a `FrameworkElement` (a control, generally) while `FindResource` looks for something in the `Resources` section.

## However

None of that is really necessary. What you **should** be doing is binding all those elements (like `Volume` to a property in your view model. Then you would have your other pages (through a locator or other pattern) set the *bound value*. This change would propagate to the control via `INotifyPropertyChanged` and you **never have to mess with the actual control**.

You could, for example use a Mediator and do this:

```
//Settings code:
MediaMediator.UpdateVolume(10);

//Mediator
public static event Action<int> VolumeUpdated;

public static void UpdateVolume(int level)
{
    //Please do the handler/null check, not here for brevity
    UpdateVolume(level);
}

//ViewModel
public int CurrentVolume {get; set;} //Actually using INotifyPropertyChanged of course
MediaMediator.VolumeUpdated += (l => CurrentVolume = l);

//View
<MediaElement ... Volume="{Binding CurrentVolume}"/>
```

Doing this, and thus following MVVM, will generally provide much better solutions to WPF/Windows Store problems. Even better, the WPF/XAML framework was effectively designed for MVVM, so they have a whole bunch of stuff already built in.

Comment: The concept that you're trying to convey here is somewhat clear to me. However, I am not able to figure out a "locator or other pattern" through which I'm supposed to access the controls. it would be great if you could supply me the info in some sort of code.

Comment: @AnmolKumar I added a sample using "Mediator" There are lots of other ways of course.

Comment: Thanks for you help, though I tried something of my own....seems to work for now! Cheers.